# Binary search algorithm in c

Tags: c, debugging

I'm trying to create a function `int find_pos(int item, int a[], int len)` that works as follows:

> Returns the index in array of the key `t` that is the the `successor` of `k`, if one exists, 
>     else return `KEY_NOT_FOUND`.

Key `t` is the *successor* of `k`, if `t` is the smallest key stored in `sda->buffer` such that `t >= k`.

```
const int KEY_NOT_FOUND = -1;

int find_pos(int item, int a[], int len) {
 int low = 0;
 int high = len-1;
 if (a[0] >= item && len == 1) {
 return 0;
 }
 if(a[0] < item && len == 1) {
 return KEY_NOT_FOUND;
 }
 while (low <= high) {
 int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
 if (a[mid] == item) {
  return mid;
 } else if (a[mid] < item) {
   low = mid + 1;
 } else {
   high = mid - 1;
 }
 if(a[high] < item) {// invalid size read of 4
  return high + 1;
 }
 }
 return KEY_NOT_FOUND;
}
```

However, it may cause invalid read size read of 4 at

```
if(a[high] < item)
```

Can somone explain(or give an example) why does this line cause invalid read size read of 4?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Congratulations on using `valgrind` to spot such problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say `low` `==` `high` `==` `0` the start of the while loop.

So, `mid` `==` `0`

Then the code does `high = mid - 1;` So, `high` is now negative, and `a[high]` is an illegal access.